# Adding authorization header to Jersey SSE Client request

Tags: java, http-headers, jersey, authorization, server-sent-events

I am using Jersey client to connect to an SSE stream. The server requires that I add a header to the http request for authorization, but I can't figure out how to add the header.

Here is my code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseurl + "/v1/devices/events/");
eventSource = EventSource.target(target).build();
eventSource.register(getEventListener());
eventSource.open();
```

Here is an example of the header I need to add:

```
Authorization: Bearer 38bb7b318cc6898c80317decb34525844bc9db55
```

Answer (score 33):

It would be something like this for Basic Authentication:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder().build();
client.register(feature);
client.register(SseFeature.class);
WebTarget target = client.target(baseurl + "/v1/devices/events/")
    .property(HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_USERNAME, "...")
    .property(HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_PASSWORD, "...");
```

...

You already get the password encoded by Jersey.

And if it is a token:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseurl + "/v1/devices/events/")
    .request("...")     
    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + "... encoded token ...");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I actually need to use the header because I have a key, not a username & password. The question has been edited to make it more clear. Sorry.

Comment: I've edited it... Left the user/password part in case it helps somebody else. In the case of the token you don't need the auth feature. Hope it helps!

Comment: My WebTarget object (javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget) does not have a header() method. I have tried this but it has no effect: `target.request().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

Comment: Sorry you are right it is indeed after the request. I've edited my answer. What version of  `Jersey` are you using? Could you post your dependencies? (`pom.xml` or equivalent) What do you mean by "no effect"? Have you debugged to see if the HTTP header is there?

Comment: [POM](https://github.com/grantwest/SparkJ/blob/master/pom.xml)
By no effect, I mean the header was not there. [Test](https://github.com/grantwest/SparkJ/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/grantwest/sparkj/SparkEventStreamTest.java)

Comment: Hello. Of course, I'm a bit lost with your code, I don't expect to understand it in 15 minutes. However, I can tell you that when you do `WebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl + "/v1/devices/events");
        target.request().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);` at `SparkEventStream` you are not doing much to your target; you are creating a request and adding a header to that request. But when you do your real request, wherever it is, there is no header added. (Not too familiar with SSE, sorry, maybe I'm saying something silly).

Comment: Its 2021 and if it fails rather use: `HttpAuthenticationFeature basicAuthFeature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(config.smsUsername(), config.smsPassword());

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .register(basicAuthFeature)
                .build();
`

Answer (score 11):

In case someone would want to add the bearer token header at the `Client` entity level itself, rather than at the `Request` entity level (in my case I had a factory method for returning preconfigured `Client` entities, so I had no way of adding the authorization header within the factory method, as `.header(...)` becomes available only after you go through the `ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(...).build().target(...).request(...)` call chain, as of Jersey 2.x):

```
// client is a javax.ws.rs.client.Client entity
Feature feature = OAuth2ClientSupport.feature("YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN");
client.register(feature);
// now you can use client.target(...).request(...).post(...), without calling .header(...) after .request(...)
```

Unfortunately (as you may have guessed) this requires a new dependency: `org.glassfish.jersey.security:oauth2-client`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>oauth2-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the complete examples

```js
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/customer/");
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "your 
secret key");
response = invocationBuilder.get();
output = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

**Dependency for jersey client**

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Using SSL + Header Key 
uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(sslUrl).port(sslServerPort).build();
sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreFile(trustStoreFile).trustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);
sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
target = client.target(uri).path(path);
Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(Object, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
response = target.request().header("key","value").post(entity);


// Using UserName & Password + Header Key 
uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(url).port(serverPort).build();
basicAuth = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username, userPassword);
client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(basicAuth).build();
target = client.target(uri).path(path);
Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(Object, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
response = target.request().header("key","value").post(entity);

// Using only Header Key 
uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(url).port(serverPort).build();
client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
target = client.target(uri).path(path);
Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(Object, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
response = target.request().header("key","value").post(entity);
```

Hope this helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is a year old but since there are not a lot to be found on that subject, I'll share my solution.

Based on suggested OAuth2Feature, I came up with this solution:

1. Create a custom feature. Feature will reference a custom filter
2. Create a custom filter of priority HEADER_DECORATOR
3. Create a HeaderProvider interface. Provider will be passed to the filter
4. Register the WebClient with the custom feature

**Header provider interface**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ISseHeaderProvider {
    Map<String, String> getHeaders();  
}
```

**Custom feature**

```
public class SseHeaderSupportFeature implements Feature {
    private final SseHeaderSupportFilter filter;


    public SseHeaderSupportFeature(ISseHeaderProvider provider) {
        this.filter = new SseHeaderSupportFilter(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(filter);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Custom filter**

```
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
public class SseHeaderSupportFilter  implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private final ISseHeaderProvider provider;

    public SseHeaderSupportFilter(@NotNull ISseHeaderProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }


    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        provider.getHeaders().forEach((k, v) -> request.getHeaders().add(k, v));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
ISseHeaderProvider provider = () -> MapBuilder.<String, String>builder().add("Authorization", "Bearer ...").build(); 
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                             .register(SseFeature.class)
                             .register(new SseHeaderSupportFeature(provider))
                             .build();
WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(getUrl()));
//EventSource eventSource = ....
```

This solution is generic and allows you to easily add an Authorization header without having to add another dependency.

Comment: Looks interesting. What does the MapBuilder look like being used for the implementation of ISseHeaderProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Following answer is useful:
[Server Sent Event Client with additional Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626412/server-sent-event-client-with-additional-cookie)
It use a customized WebTarget to add cookie and the same way on header also work.

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderWebTarget implements WebTarget {

    private WebTarget base;

    private String token;

    public AuthorizationHeaderWebTarget(WebTarget base, String token) {
        this.base = base;
        this.token = token;
    }

    // Inject that cookie whenever someone requests a Builder (like EventSource does):
    public Invocation.Builder request() {
        return base.request().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token);
    }

    public Invocation.Builder request(String... paramArrayOfString) {
        return base.request(paramArrayOfString).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token);
    }

    public Invocation.Builder request(MediaType... paramArrayOfMediaType) {
        return base.request(paramArrayOfMediaType).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token);
    }

    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return base.getConfiguration();
    }

    //All other methods from WebTarget are delegated as-is:

    public URI getUri() {
        return base.getUri();
    }

    public UriBuilder getUriBuilder() {
        return base.getUriBuilder();
    }

    public WebTarget path(String paramString) {
        return base.path(paramString);
    }

    public WebTarget matrixParam(String paramString, Object... paramArrayOfObject) {
        return base.matrixParam(paramString, paramArrayOfObject);
    }

    public WebTarget property(String paramString, Object paramObject) {
        return base.property(paramString, paramObject);
    }

    public WebTarget queryParam(String paramString, Object... paramArrayOfObject) {
        return base.queryParam(paramString, paramArrayOfObject);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Class<?> paramClass, Class<?>... paramArrayOfClass) {
        return base.register(paramClass, paramArrayOfClass);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Class<?> paramClass, int paramInt) {
        return base.register(paramClass, paramInt);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Class<?> paramClass, Map<Class<?>, Integer> paramMap) {
        return base.register(paramClass, paramMap);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return base.register(paramClass);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Object paramObject, Class<?>... paramArrayOfClass) {
        return base.register(paramObject, paramArrayOfClass);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Object paramObject, int paramInt) {
        return base.register(paramObject, paramInt);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Object paramObject, Map<Class<?>, Integer> paramMap) {
        return base.register(paramObject, paramMap);
    }

    public WebTarget register(Object paramObject) {
        return base.register(paramObject);
    }

    public WebTarget resolveTemplate(String paramString, Object paramObject) {
        return base.resolveTemplate(paramString, paramObject);
    }

    public WebTarget resolveTemplate(String paramString, Object paramObject, boolean paramBoolean) {
        return base.resolveTemplate(paramString, paramObject, paramBoolean);
    }

    public WebTarget resolveTemplateFromEncoded(String paramString, Object paramObject) {
        return base.resolveTemplateFromEncoded(paramString, paramObject);
    }

    public WebTarget resolveTemplates(Map<String, Object> paramMap) {
        return base.resolveTemplates(paramMap);
    }

    public WebTarget resolveTemplates(Map<String, Object> paramMap, boolean paramBoolean) {
        return base.resolveTemplates(paramMap, paramBoolean);
    }

    public WebTarget resolveTemplatesFromEncoded(Map<String, Object> paramMap) {
        return base.resolveTemplatesFromEncoded(paramMap);
    }

}
```

Following is the code to use it:

```
EventSource eventSource = new EventSource(new AuthorizationHeaderWebTarget(target, token));
eventSource.register(new EventListener() {
       public void onEvent(final InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
               //...
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer38bb7b318cc6898c80317decb34525844bc9db55");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jercy client using header in websource

```
Client client=Client.create();          
WebResource webresource=client.resource(urlLink);
ClientResponse clientResponse=webresource.header("authorization", accessToken)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
```